# Array of objects convert to object with keys by item field value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have this array:

```
const demo = [
  { key: 'apple', a: 'b', c: 1 },
  { key: 'banana', a: 'f', c: 3 },
  { key: 'orange', a: 'j', c: 8 },
];
```

I can get info about "banana" by using:

```
demo.find(item => item.key === 'banana')
```

Instead I would like to have this associative and access like this:

```
demo.banana.c
```

So I need to somehow get this:

```
const demo = {
  'apple': { key: 'apple', a: 'b', c: 1 },
  'banana': { key: 'banana', a: 'f', c: 3 },
  'orange': { key: 'orange', a: 'j', c: 8 },
};
```

Or without "key" inside, it does not matter.

What would be simplest solution? Some simple (maybe one-line) approach with ES6? If not, Lodash instead?

Answer (score 4):

```js
const demo = [{
    key: 'apple',
    a: 'b',
    c: 1
  },
  {
    key: 'banana',
    a: 'f',
    c: 3
  },
  {
    key: 'orange',
    a: 'j',
    c: 8
  },
];

const solution = demo.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.key] = cur;
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(solution)
```

Comment: I will accept this question but please provide any explanation, description. Code-only answers are against stackoverflow rules so this answer can be deleted later.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.fromEntries` to build the object, and destructuring to extract the key from the rest of the original object:

```js
const demo = [
  { key: 'apple', a: 'b', c: 1 },
  { key: 'banana', a: 'f', c: 3 },
  { key: 'orange', a: 'j', c: 8 },
];

let result = Object.fromEntries(demo.map(({key, ...rest}) => [key, rest]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use lodash's `_.keyBy()`:

```js
const demo = [
  { key: 'apple', a: 'b', c: 1 },
  { key: 'banana', a: 'f', c: 3 },
  { key: 'orange', a: 'j', c: 8 },
];

const result = _.keyBy(demo, 'key');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```